# How to use <div> properly in Struts 2

Tags: java, html, arraylist, struts2

I have a list in JSP page which is iterated by Struts tag and when I try to create `<div>` for each iteration it is not working fine.

**Here is my code:**

```
<div style="height:300px;width:700px;border:solid 2px white;overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;">

        <s:if test="#request.questions !=null && #request.questions.size()>0">
          <s:set var="id"  value="-1" />
               
           <s:iterator value="#request.questions" status="index" var="ques">
                
             <s:if test="%{#id != surveyId}"> 
               name <s:property value="surveyId"/>
                <s:set var="id"  value="surveyId"/>
                </s:if>
              
              <s:div "  id="questionNumber<s:property value='sortOrder'/>">
                    <span class="questionCode"><s:property value="questioncode"/>. </span> 
                     
                    <span class="questionText"><s:property value="questionname"/> </span>
                
                    <s:div class="answersBlock">
                        <s:div><label class="answerLabel">Ans. <s:property value="answername"/> </label></s:div>
                    </s:div>
                
                </s:div>
                
                </s:iterator>
        </s:if>
        <s:else>
            No Survey Taken Yet.
        </s:else></p>
</div>
```

Here I am getting date like in below format

```
id 281
q1: question
ans: -----

id: 282
q1:question
ans: ---
q2: question
ans:----
q3:question
and:----
```

now what I want here is to create two separate `<div>` for `id`s 281, 282, and put content of  each `id` in a different `<div>`.

I am getting data dynamically, so it could be  more then  2 `id`'s, so on the bases of them create a `<div>` and one `id` can have multiple question answer.

Comment: Just use a plain div-s.

Comment: Struts div is Ajax based, and recommended to use jQuery plugin

Comment: `<s:div "  id="questionNumber<s:property value='sortOrder'/>">` is non-sensical in multiple ways, the most critical being that you cannot nest JSP tags like that.

Comment: `<s:div>` is not ajax based.

Answer (score 1):

You are tried to use [`<s:div>`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/dojo-div.html) tag like HTML `<div>` but it's wrong tag usage. The `<s:div>` is an Ajax tag used to load HTML content via Ajax call. But you don't need it, just use HTML `<div>`.

Also note, if you are using Struts tags make sure you don't nest them in Struts tag's head or attributes. You can nest tags only in the body of Struts tags.

```xml
<div id="questionNumber<s:property value='sortOrder'/>">
    <span class="questionCode"><s:property value="questioncode"/>. </span> 

    <span class="questionText"><s:property value="questionname"/> </span>

    <div class="answersBlock">
        <div><label class="answerLabel">Ans. <s:property value="answername"/> </label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```